# How can I find Video from Facebook Page Using FB Graph API?

Tags: java, api

Below is my java code and I have uploaded youtube video in my page, but I can't get detail of this uploaded Video, also I read Facebook developer document but I didn't get any detail.

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
Connection<Video> result = fbClient.fetchConnection("*Page-id*/videos/uploaded", Video.class);

        for (List<Video> page : result) {
            for (Video aPost : page) {
                System.out.println("getDescription ==> " + aPost.getDescription());
                System.out.println("getTitle ==> " + aPost.getTitle());   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint `pageid/videos/...` only concerns videos which are published (if you scheduled your video for later it won't appear here).

When you upload a video, FB returns an array with its own video ID, in order to get its details you should use directly the endpoint `videoid/`, then if video isn't finished being processed by FB, or isn't published yet, you'll be still able to check for its status and details through this endpoint.
Then once published you can have its insights too directly on the endpoint `videoid/video_insights/`.

Use the [FB Graph Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to make all your tests.